# Directive scope undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make an http request in my controller, but my `$scope.dataSource` comes back as `undefined`, and I am not sure why. I build the directive like this:

```
app.directive('users', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/config/users.html',
        scope: {
            dataSource: '@'
        },
        controller: function($scope, $http){
            $http({
                url: $scope.dataSource
            }).success(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And the html like this, but it doesn't run the ajax request because the `$scope.dataSource` is `undefined`.

```
<users class="col-sm-4" data-source="/data/users.json"></users>
```

Comment: Try changing `data-source` to `source`. I can't remember where, but I though I saw somewhere that `data-` attributes don't play well with custom directives

Comment: @vinayakj this doesn't have to do with AJAX, the problem is that the URL he is trying to pass into his directive is coming up undefined

Comment: @Sean Using just `source` also gives `undefined`

Comment: The variable `scope` will then just be undefined

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn you made sure to change everything to match `source` and not `dataSource` right? This plunker shows it as defined when I change it to `source` but when I change it to `dataSource` it messes up http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview

Comment: Does $scope show as undefined as well?

Comment: @vinayakj that worked somewhat, `$attrs.dataSource` is undefined, but  `$attrs.source` is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move it to a watch function:

```
app.directive('users', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/config/users.html',
        scope: {
            source: '@'
        },
        link: function($scope){
            $scope.watch('source', function(source) {
              if (dataSource !== undefined) {
                $http({
                    url: source
                }).success(function(data){
                    $scope.data = data;
                });
              }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you can use `$http` in the `link` without defining it?

Comment: Yes I get it from the first line

Comment: didn't downvote either but why would you need the watch ?

Comment: huh... I didn't know you could do that. let me try.

Comment: the watch wasn't needed, and converting `data-source` to `source` worked

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `controller` you need a `link` function and pass the `scope` and `$http` to it.

```
app.directive('users', function($http){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/config/users.html',
        scope: {
            dataSource: '@'
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            $http({
                url: scope.dataSource
            }).success(function(data) {
                $parent.$scope.data = data; // where data is a model in parent controller.
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$attrs` allows me to get the value like this:

```
app.directive('users', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/config/users.html',
        scope: {
            dataSource: '@'
        },
        controller: function($scope, $http, $attrs){
            $http({
                url: $attrs.source
            }).success(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I still use `dataSource` in the scope and html, but use `$attrs.source` in the controller.